# MySQL query: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `course` SET 
    `courselocation_id` = :courselocation_id,
    `courselocation_period_id` = :courselocation_period_id,
    `start_date` = :start_date,
    `instructor_id` = :instructor_id,
    `edited_by` = :edited_by,
    `edited_at` = :edited_at
WHERE `id` = :id";

$params = [
    ":courselocation_id" => 4,
    ":courselocation_period_id" => 8,
    ":start_date" => "2018-09-17",
    ":instructor_id" => 17,
    ":edited_by" => 1,
    ":edited_at" => 1536828797,
    ":id" => 2533
];

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
```

is executed normally, the data is written, but I get an error:

> PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /path/to/script.php on line 188

Line 188 is actually the one with $query->execute($params)

How can I fix that?

**Update:**

It really looks like another query was the cause of this warning just like @RiggsFolly suggested. When i commented out this one, the other one was not executed and that's why it wen't 'under the radar'. The other query had a misspelled parameter (instead of :intitutionID there was :institutionId).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full text of the error. Also, highlight the line number in the code that causes the warning.

Comment: _The query gets executed normally, data is written, but i get a warning_ Then the warning is not coming from this query. Show us ALL the error message and check the line number on the error is coming from this piece of code

Comment: I updated my question with full warning that i get in error.log file. The thing is that the query executes, and it is written to db, but why the warning? :) If the warning would not come from this query, then (when i commented out that part) i should still get a warning, but i wasn't..

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like another query was the cause of this warning just like @RiggsFolly suggested. When i commented out this one, the other one was not executed and that's why it wen't 'under the radar'. The other query had a misspelled parameter (instead of :intitutionID there was :institutionId)..